# BitBucket API: How to get a list of branches from a repository UUID

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

BitBucket API so far has been an interesting experience, let's say.

We have sometimes very brief generated docs across various URLs with bits of functionality peppered between `bitbucket.org/rest/api/1.0`, `api.bitbucket.org/2.0` etc and a way to get a list of repositories:

```
GET https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories?role=x
```

This response contains a UUID for the repo which the docs say:

> This can be used as a substitute for
>   the slug segment in URLs. **Doing this guarantees your URLs will survive
>   renaming of the repository** by its owner, or even transfer of the
>   repository to a different user.

Sounds like common sense to me! So how about [getting a list of branches](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/refs/branches#get)?

```
GET https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/refs/branches
```

`UUID` can be used in place of `repo_slug` which is good. But it also bizarrely wants `username` (which can confusingly also be the org name). So the point about being resilient to moving the repository is pointless. And does the list of repositories return this? **Nope**.

So how, using the repository UUID, do I find out the `username`, or better yet get a list of branches with just the UUID which would be sensible thing to support like on GitLab/GitHub? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like once you have the repo UUID, you can substitute `%7B%7D` as an empty user/team name.

From [this documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/uri-uuid#repo-obj):

> Once you have the UUID for a repository you no longer need a username
>   or team name to make the API call so long as you use an empty field.
>
> This helps you resolve repositories no matter if the username or team
>   name changes.
>
> Call with team name (1team) and repository name (moxie):
>
> `curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/1team/moxie`
>
> Call with UUID and empty field:
>
> `curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/%7B%7D/%7B21fa9bf8-b5b2-4891-97ed-d590bad0f871%7D`
>
> Call with UUID and teamname:
>
> `curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/1team/%7B21fa9bf8-b5b2-4891-97ed-d590bad0f871%7D`

Comment: Yes! Phew! Exactly what I was hoping thanks. Was ready to bin support for BitBucket. Will try it out and mark as the answer if it works.